# Macbook Drivers for Samsung devices

Tags: macos, mac, android

I'm looking for Mac drivers for two Samsung Devices: One mobile phone and one tablet.

I've looked on the Samsung site and found a download for the Tab3 but not my old Galaxy Ace 2. I couldn't find a Mac download for either one.

Where can I find these drivers?

Comment: I have iOS currently when the devices are plugged into USB nothing is picked up !!

Answer (score 0):

A google search for the Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 returned links to Ace 2 product pages which has download link to Windows and Mac software, did you try to download and use them? Try to google your second device model, you will get links to product page.

link 1
http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/others/GT-S7560ZKMBMC

link 2
http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-I8160OKABTU

Comment: Hi yes downloaded link 2 SAMSUNG Kies (Mac),PC Sync
MAC OS 10.5 ~ 10.7, 27.94 MB, DMG, MULTI LANGUAGE
VERSION : 2.0.0.13023_10_1  and still can't pick up device when USB is attached.. The device is activated when attached but now acknowledgement from laptop !!